# Unsuccessful place inference - status code 20

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using the android place picker and getting this error:

```
com.google.android.gms.persistent I/Places: afoc.a:301: Unsuccessful place inference - status code 20
```

The place picker opens and shows the map with current location but no nearby locations are shown.

Code:

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), Constants.PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GooglePlayServices Not Available");
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GooglePlayServices Repairable");
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you included some code so we can see what it is that you're trying to do here.

Comment: added my PlacePicker code.